# Why does Bruce became angry at Niagara Falls?

Tags: plot-explanation, bruce-almighty

In ***Bruce Almighty*** (2003), the main character Bruce is reporting live at Niagara Falls. It shows Evan speaking for him  and then directs the camera to Bruce, so he finally gets a chance to be a live anchor. But Bruce becomes angry. Why does Bruce became angry at the Niagara Falls live anchoring scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **Anchor** is the main presenter of a news show. They present or introduce every story, headlining the show for the entire night.

A **correspondent** or field reporter is just that. They do reports from the field, away from the studio.

Bruce specifically was a **Slice of Life** correspondent. He wasn't reporting important news. He was reporting boring happy news about general events in the city. He wasn't reporting important, human interest stories or anything. These reporters are seen as jokes amongst their peers. When the camera changes from the studio to Bruce, they call him **Wacky Bruce**. It's demeaning.

So Bruce is angry that he's getting stuck doing unimportant work and getting no respect, while Evan gets the most important job of a news show, the main on air personality. Bruce is stuck getting wet, when Evan is in the comfy chair in the studio.

Bruce's anger comes from his ego and self-entitlement, a lack of pride in his assigned job, which is the overall theme of the movie.

Answer (score 1):

Bruce was not an anchor in that scene, he was a correspondent.  If I'm not mistaken, he had just found out that Evan was going to be the new anchor, a job Bruce coveted.  After working so hard for a promotion and finding out his promotion went to a person he felt had inferior talent, Bruce went on a rant during his live telecast.

Answer (score 1):

Bruce became angry because Evan Baxter was his competitor and he was going to be new anchor and will get promotion. And Bruce also said that ""First off, I want to add another congratulations to Evan Baxter. It's good to see what someone with real talent can accomplish when great opportunities are given to him instead of me. Anyway"

So Bruce was frustrated already from his mind, that was the reason.